# Fallback language for settings bundle localization

Tags: ios, ios7, localization, application-settings, settings.bundle

I have created a settings bundle, with a Root.plist file. This file is in english. I have also created localizations for Norwegian. As expected, when the phones language is english, my settings are in english, and when the phones language is in norwegian, the settings are in norwegian. The weird thing is that if the phones language is some other language, the settings are in norwegian. I would expect it to default to english. I have tried deleteing the app, restarting the phone etc. I have also tried to create a folder called Base.lproj and put the english translations in there. It still defaults to norwegian. Why?

Comment: @Danjiel hjertholm are you using default NSLocalizedString(<@"key">, <@"comment">) ? or some else..?

Comment: What is the development language setting in `info.plist`?

Comment: @rckoenes: Localization native development region = en

Comment: @Ilesh: No, the settings strings are localized as described here: http://useyourloaf.com/blog/2010/12/17/localizing-iphone-app-settings-strings.html